# thunderbird cannot login to apache james

Tags: apache, email, authentication, mail-server, james

So far as I can tell, [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html) is running correctly:

```
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# bin/james-cli.sh -h localhost listdomainslocalhost
127.0.1.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.1.1

listdomains command executed sucessfully in 262 ms.

root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# bin/james-cli.sh -h localhost listusersa@localhost
b@localhost
thufir@localhost

listusers command executed sucessfully in 277 ms.

root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# telnet localhost 143 -l thufir@localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK JAMES IMAP4rev1 Server  Server dur.bounceme.net is ready.
login
* BYE Unknown command.
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby#
```

So, I'm trying to login with tomcat:

[image]

Of course, that fails.  Here's how the account was setup:

[image]

Should the server names be prepended with imap and smtp?  Why won't thunderbird login?  (Yes, I'm using the correct password.)

If this would be better to troubleshoot with Java, I can do that, but it seemed prudent to start with thunderbird.

James shows the login attempts as:

```
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby# tail log/james-server.log 
INFO  03:38:56,180 | james.imapserver | ID=10307467 Connection closed for 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:39:42,277 | james.imapserver | ID=18745390 Connection established from 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:40:16,779 | james.imapserver | ID=18745390 Too many authentication failures. Closing connection.
INFO  03:40:16,801 | james.imapserver | ID=18745390 Connection closed for 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:40:16,854 | james.imapserver | ID=18407750 Connection established from 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:40:20,028 | james.imapserver | ID=18407750 Connection closed for 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:42:04,682 | james.imapserver | ID=295845 Connection established from 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:42:14,286 | james.imapserver | ID=295845 Connection closed for 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:48:17,081 | james.imapserver | ID=9571677 Connection established from 127.0.0.1
INFO  03:48:17,143 | james.imapserver | ID=9571677 Connection closed for 127.0.0.1
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4.derby#
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server name should be as is, without any prefixes. It would be best to put there real server name. In your case "dur.bounceme.net".

Or you can play with "hosts" file and assign an alias to your server (i.e. you can add smtp and imap, or just mail prefixes to an alias of the server if you like). For a linux machine you can find it in /etc/hosts and add e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1     imap.localhost
127.0.0.1     smtp.localhost
```

or:

```
<server's IP>     <server alias>
```

This way you can have two additional aliases for the same machine if you would like that, but it is not needed.